# Use Android Preference Screen Fragment without saving to Shared Preferences?

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin in VS2013 to create a cross platform application.  I have a library in my Data Access Layer which abstract away saving the standard settings to an XML file which works fine across all platforms, so I would like to use it for storing preferences.

I do, however, really like the "PreferenceScreen" and "PreferenceActivity" layouts as they certainly make the data binding easier.

Is there a way to use either, but have they use my own save method?

If not, is there a layout scheme which closely mimics the layout?

Comment: What keeps you from designing your XML file in such a way that you can load it directly as shared preferences in android? I have a option in my app to store preferences to a file which can be reloaded after a reinstall of the app. Though it is not, that file could just as well be an XML.

Comment: Pure ignorance is my only reason.  I was hoping to keep the DAL and DL completely device independent, but I can implement an adapter that will use Preferences instead.  I am having a difficult time finding any documentation on Preferences in C#, which isn't helping my cause.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry cannot help with C#. I am developing purely native.

Comment: @BayssMekanique how do you expect this Adapter should work? Which preferences feature you need? The storage you need is `SharedPreferences` on Android?

Comment: I actually am trying to avoid the SharedPreferences storage features, while still using the front end preferences UI.  I like that there is a save triggered no field exits and the UI seems to adapt cleanly across multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution was to move to MvvmCross and use the "Settings" plugin by Cheesebaron.
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins